# parallel requests in expressjs/mongo do not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, request

It seems that when I do this in frontend (using Angular, but I think that doesn't matter)

```
$http.get("url1"); //this request takes 2 seconds in the backend
$http.get("url2").success(function{console.log('end');})
```

using express.js, my backend code looks something like this:

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
express = require('express')
app = express()

app.get('/url1', (req, res)->
        //code using Mongo that lasts >2 seconds
        res.send(result);
);

app.get('/url2', (req, res)->
    //code using Mongo
);
```

The logging of the 'end' string should be called after url2 was ended, but it is indeed called only after url1 and url2 are called. Is this an issue with expressjs or mongo ? If yes, what node framework do you recommend to manage multiple parallel requests ?

If I remove the first line $http.get("url1");  The console.log('end') is instant.

Comment: It may be something in the url1 routine that is blocking the event loop. For instance, iterating over a large dataset. You should be able to witness the Network request from the client's debugger tool and then the receiving of the request server side with a console.log early within url2. What is occurring in the url1 routine?

Comment: Yep that must be it. I'm looping over each element to convert it into another format. I have checked the duration of both of the parts, and the mongodb part takes 735ms and the iteration 3480s

Comment: I've put together a small module called [eachtick](https://github.com/kevireilly/eachtick) which can help mitigate this by treating each iteration as an asynchronous task. This will keep the event loop open and receiving API requests and otherwise. The trade off is iteration speed versus an open event loop.

Comment: I finally used .each in Mongo instead of .toArray, and used setInterval

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongo, but the involvement of setInterval doesn't seem like part of an appropriate approach. Glad you got it working though!